# github large file issue while trying multiple commit

Tags: github, bitbucket, git-lfs

I am using GitHub and BitBucket, both as remote origins. The repository which is on GitHub does not have any node_modules folder. Everything is working good on BitBucket branches, the issue is only happening with GitHub.

When executing `git push origin main`, I get the following:

```
Enumerating objects: 53201, done.
Counting objects: 100% (53201/53201), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31418/31418), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52848/52848), 182.23 MiB | 14.93 MiB/s, done.
Total 52848 (delta 18735), reused 52363 (delta 18341), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (18735/18735), completed with 224 local objects.
remote: warning: File resources/node_modules/.cache/default-development/0.pack is 57.98 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: f3d018319ecb64b1df1c69c43ff901382e413fca7dfb92927d239a05409b3cfa
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File resources/node_modules/.cache/default-development/7.pack is 132.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File resources/node_modules/.cache/default-development/6.pack is 146.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/abc/abc.git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/abc/abc.git'
```

I used the lfs and cleared cache, but still have the same issue. I also have included my `resources/node_modules` folder in `.gitignore` file, but also get the same error; tried to delete it entirely - still the same error.

Comment: Do you see the file locally? It seems like this file is being pushed. GitHub has a policy of limiting the maximum file size.

Comment: The file may be ignored, but it still exists in some commit you're trying to push.